# WPF: How to change TransitioningContentControl background color?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I work with MahApps, use this contentcontrol to show a License text read from a file.

```
    <controls:TransitioningContentControl Transition="Down" Content="{Binding LicenseDocument}" FontFamily="{DynamicResource ContentFontFamily}" FontSize="{DynamicResource NormalFontSize}" Visibility="{Binding LicenseInfoVisibility}" TabIndex="0" Margin="0,-5,0,10"/>

public FrameworkElement LicenseDocument
{
  get;
  set;
}
public void InitDoc()
{
    try
    {
        const string licenseFullFile = @"License.rtf";
        using (
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(licenseFullFile)))
            )
        {
            FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument();
            new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd).Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
            RichTextBox box = new RichTextBox(document)
            {
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto,
                IsReadOnly = true
            };
            LicenseInfoVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.LicenseDocument = box;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception xException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(xException);
    }
}
```

It works ok when I use

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
```

There is my resourcedictionary

```
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Cobalt.xaml" />-->
        <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />-->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

But if I use BaseDark then richtext background and the font colors are black.

What is wrong?

Comment: It works for me... Did you include all the other standard packs, like `Fonts.xaml`, `Color.xaml`, etc?

Comment: Yes, sure, see above i have edited the question.

Comment: Is your dictionary in your `Window.xaml` or `App.xaml` ?

Comment: The dictionary is in App.xaml

Comment: Check your `Output` window for any warnings or exceptions.

Comment: Post print screens you get for `BaseLight` and `BaseDark`.

Comment: In my `License.rtf` document, i set foreground color to `Automatic` and background to `No color`. Perhaps you're setting it explicitly to `Black` ?

Comment: Also, your `BaseDark` has `Agree to license` set, while `BaseLight` doesn't... not sure that could have an effect on your side.

Comment: Do you mean: need to change colors in the rtf file or in control? how to do it?

Comment: I mean in the `rtf` file.

Comment: How to do it in file?

Comment: Highlight your text in your editor and then right-click. The context popup menu should present you with the option to do so. I'm using Word, but whatever editor you're using should give you similar option.

Comment: Please add your answer I will mark it. Thank you!!!! I set font color automatic and it works in both themes.

Comment: In Word, this is what you should see: https://imgur.com/v3qKZAd. The `A` with a red underline is where you change foreground, and the button to the left of it you change background.

Comment: Btw, if i explicitly set foreground to black in my rtf, then i get the same result as you do.

Comment: ok, thank you, do "Answer" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `License.rtf` has `foreground` set to **Automatic** and `background` set to **No Color**.

XAML:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Application3" 
                  x:Class="MahApps.Metro.Application3.MainWindow"
                  Title="MainWindow"
                  Height="350"
                  Width="525">
<Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</Controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Controls:TransitioningContentControl Transition="Down" 
                                          Content="{Binding LicenseDocument}" 
                                          FontFamily="{DynamicResource ContentFontFamily}" 
                                          FontSize="{DynamicResource NormalFontSize}" 
                                          Visibility="{Binding LicenseInfoVisibility}" 
                                          TabIndex="0" Margin="0,-5,0,10"/>
</Grid>
```

BaseLight:

[image]

BaseDark:

[image]